# Free Pascal : Console text modification (Beginner)

Tags: dynamic, text, console, edit, freepascal

My question is simple, i'd like to know if it is possible with free pascal (no delphi or anything else) to "edit" text written in console with the function write() (or another one doing the same).

For example :

```
Program Test;
Begin
 Writeln('This is a test');
 FUNCTION('This test has been edited');
End.
```

Output :

```
This test has been edited
```

I know i can do it like this :

```
Program Test;
Uses crt;
Begin
 Writeln('This is a test');
 ClrScr;
 Writeln('This test has been edited');
End.
```

But i don't want to use ClrScr.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `GotoXY(X, Y)` function

```
 Writeln('This is a test');
 Readln;
 GotoXY(1, 1);
 Writeln('This test has been edited');
 Readln;
```